# Freez/working terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I know that terminal is continuing a job without interrupting it?

I have run the following git command:

> clone git://ligo-vcs.phys.uwm.edu/lalsuite.gituote

and it seems to be frozen after a while, but I'm not sure. How can I check if it is frozen?

Answer (score 3):

You can check its:

1. cpu usage -- using `top`
2. IO usage -- using `iotop`
3. network activity -- using `ntop`, `nagios`, `jnettop`

This should give you some sense if it's still doing things.

Comment: I'm at Ubuntu 13.10. The last two do not work: command not found!

Comment: Yes, those are non-standard commands you'd need to install. They can come handy, in cases such as this, so you should.